# Update json file value based on key match from another Json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

**Objective:** Match key and Override values in  json element values on two json files

**Input:**

**Source json file looks like:**

```
{"CLIENT_CODE":"client-d",
    "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID":"abced-edfgh-dk6dkk-97dke",
    "location":"easteurope"}
```

**Target json file looks like:**

```
{"CLIENT_CODE":"dummy",
    "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID":"dummy",
    "prefix":"orp",
    "location":"westeurope",
    "address_space":"10.0.0.0/16",
    "aad_login_name":"abcd.onmicrosoft.com",
    "aad_login_object_id":"dummy",
    "aad_login_tenant_id":"dummy",
    "bastion_allocation_method":"Static",
    "bastion_sku_type":"premium",
    "kv_sku_name":"premium",
    "storage_account_tier":"Standard",
    "storage_account_replication_type":"LRS",
    "storage_account_kind":"StorageV2",
    "sql_pool_sku_name":"DW100C",
    "node_size_family":"MemoryOptimized"}
```

**Output Expected:**

```
{"CLIENT_CODE":"client-d",
    "ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID":"abced-edfgh-dk6dkk-97dke",
    "prefix":"orp",
    "location":"easteurope",
    "address_space":"10.0.0.0/16",
    "aad_login_name":"abcd.onmicrosoft.com",
    "aad_login_object_id":"dummy",
    "aad_login_tenant_id":"dummy",
    "bastion_allocation_method":"Static",
    "bastion_sku_type":"premium",
    "kv_sku_name":"premium",
    "storage_account_tier":"Standard",
    "storage_account_replication_type":"LRS",
    "storage_account_kind":"StorageV2"}
```

**What I tried:**

```
import json

with open("D:\ABTest\source.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dataset1 = json.loads(f.read())
    #print(dataset1)

with open("D:\ABTest\\target.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    dataset2 = json.loads(f.read())
    #print(dataset2)

if dataset1.keys() == dataset2.keys():
   dataset2.update(dataset1)
   print(dataset2)
```

But I am not getting any output

**Update1 :** Now I am able to write it in 3rd file. But not able to update same 2nd file which is `target.json`

```
import json

with open("D:\ABTest\source.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d1 = json.loads(f.read())

with open("D:\ABTest\\target.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d2 = json.loads(f.read())

for key in d1.keys():
    if key in d2.keys():
       d2[key] = d1[key]
       print(d2)

with open('D:\ABTest\combined.json', 'w', ) as f:
     json.dump(d2, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

**Update 2:**

I made it work. Updated working code in answer section.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the code that I tried

Comment: Your input and output data is to complex for a good minimal working example. Would be nice if you could reduce that. In the current state your queston doesn't help anyone and it is hard to see the difference between in- and output data. But I assume your question is more about updating dictionaries instead of json data and handling json files.

Comment: @buhtz I am able to solve the issue what worked is `for key in d1.keys():if key in d2.keys():  d2[key] = d1[key]`. I have updated my solution... All I needed is to compare json (which will be in dictionary format) then if key matches, then update dict2 with value from dict1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have now have following worked. It can help someone looking at similar issue

```
import json

# input file for d1
with open("D:\ABTest\source.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d1 = json.load(f)

# input file for d2
with open("D:\ABTest\\target.json", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d2 = json.loads(f)

# output file
with open('D:\ABTest\\target.json', 'w', ) as f:
    # update values in d2 with values from d1
    for key in d2:
        try:
            # raise an KeyError if d1 doesn't have the key
            d2[key] = d1[key]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    json.dump(d2, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

print(d2)
```

Eliminate the `if` statement and replace it with a `try...except...` block make the code more pythonic and performant.

Comment: I improved the readability of your code. I also improved the algorithm. You iterated over the keys of `d1`. But it makes more sense if you iterate over the keys of `d2` only. I also removed the `if` statement.